# Error [CredentialsError]: Missing credentials in config, but only when running on Fargate AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-fargate, aws-sdk-js

I built a dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file to import the environment. The environment looks like this:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX
ROLE_ARN=XXX
BUCKET_NAME=BUCKET
AWS_PROFILE=default
AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=[path]
AWS_CONFIG_FILE=[path]
AWS_REGION=region
```

When I tried to upload file to S3, it works perfect when i run that docker on my PC using `docker-compose up` but whenever I ran it on Fargate, I got this error

```
Error [CredentialsError]: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
    at Request.extractError (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at Request.emit (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at callNextListener (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/myuser/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:307:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:322:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12) {
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  time: 2020-06-11T12:47:25.609Z,
  requestId: '0d6fd3d4-df21-4195-a6e4-de470006429d',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 80.8300420619739,
  originalError: {
    message: 'Could not load credentials from ChainableTemporaryCredentials',
    code: 'CredentialsError',
    time: 2020-06-11T12:47:25.609Z,
    requestId: '0d6fd3d4-df21-4195-a6e4-de470006429d',
    statusCode: 403,
    retryable: false,
    retryDelay: 80.8300420619739,
    originalError: {
      message: 'Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1',
      code: 'CredentialsError',
      time: 2020-06-11T12:47:25.609Z,
      requestId: '0d6fd3d4-df21-4195-a6e4-de470006429d',
      statusCode: 403,
      retryable: false,
      retryDelay: 80.8300420619739,
      originalError: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a part of my code for the credentials:

```
    var envCreds = new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS');
    s3.config.credentials = envCreds;
    s3.config.credentials = new AWS.ChainableTemporaryCredentials({
        params: {
            RoleArn: process.env.ROLE_ARN,
            region: process.env.AWS_REGION
        }
    });
```

I need to switch role. I have tried using SharedIniFileCredentials but no lucks, I always got AccessDenied.

I used console log to log the credential, the only difference is
`region` was set to `ap-northeast-1` on Fargate while it was `undefined` on local. Since the bucket and Fargate are on the same server. I really can't find out what is this region from and how this matters.

Is this a bug or was I wrong somewhere? Why it ran fine on my PC but not fargate? Is that because of environment conflict in Fargate? I have been in this trouble for days, any helps will be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I figured  out, thanks to @Marcin. You should not set any credential or role in Docker running in Fargate task. You need to create a task role with enough AWS permission and assign it to the task. When I ran on local, the code will assume the default profile with role arn so it worked fine.

Again, don't commit any credentials to your code.

Comment: You hardcode all the credentials in your task? Usually for ecs you use [task role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) for giving it necessary permissions.

Comment: @Marcin I tried to hard code them too, no luck

Comment: My point is that you shoudn't do this. Its very bad practice. Task roles should be used. Have you tried using them?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know container and task also need role, I thought full permission is enough. I think that's why it's different running on local and fargate. I'll try. Thanks @Marcin

Comment: No problem. I will put it as an answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

A proposed solution to the authentication issues is to use [IAM Roles for Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html), instead of hard coding access and secret keys into the code or passing them as env variables.

The use of task roles is in line with AWS **good practice** of not hard coding any credentials and using temporary credentials instead:

> With IAM roles for Amazon ECS tasks, you can specify an **IAM role that can be used by the containers in a task**. Applications must sign their AWS API requests with AWS credentials, and this feature provides a strategy for managing credentials for your applications to use, **similar to the way that Amazon EC2 instance profiles** provide credentials to EC2 instances.

Comment: I don't get it. I already set IAM role that have full permission for task and container, but it still does not work.

Comment: @HùngNguyễn You may need to adjust [credentials provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html) for your app.

Comment: @HùngNguyễn For ECS, you can try [ECSCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ECSCredentials.html) provider.

Comment: I got AccessDenied using those, the role of my current id doesn't include uploading file to s3. that's why i need `ChainableTemporaryCredentials`

Comment: Oh right, adding assumed role to trust policies works. In addition, if you already set full permission to upload file from fargate to s3, you don't need to assume role in code any more.